# How do I use a Semaphore with asyncio.as_completed in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, semaphore

**SETUP:** I have a large list (over 100+) of tasks (coroutines) that connect to a REST API database server. The coroutines use a client connection pool. I think that the client connection pool is cutting me off, because I am not able to get all my results. I also think that I could use a Semaphore to limit the concurrent connections to the API server, and get all my results before my script finishes. Here's a minimal example:

```
q = Queue(-1)
progress = tqdm(total=total_hits)
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1)
for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
    async with sem:
        res = await task
        q.put_nowait(res["data"])
        progress.update(len(res["data"]))
        while res["links"].get("next", None) is not None:
            res = await client.get_json_async(res["links"]["next"])
            q.put_nowait(res["data"])
            progress.update(len(res["data"]))
```

**PROBLEM:** I know that I have 10,000 data points to capture. However, I consistently only capture about half of those. I think it's because the client is limiting my TCP connections to the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume this is your main data acquisition routine and it as the primary task of your app.  The `as_completed` function runs all the coroutines in `tasks` concurrently.  Each time one of those tasks finishes, the loop runs once.  Since your semaphore is inside the loop, it does nothing (if my main assumption is correct) - there can never be two coroutines from the list `tasks` that attempt to acquire the semaphone concurrently.  However, I think it's very unlikely that half your data point captures just fail silently.  Surely there would be some traceback or exception thrown in those cases.

Comment: @PaulCornelius that’s a great thought. I didn’t think of that… so the semaphore lock needs to happen prior to the loop. Hmm. I’m not sure how to do that?

Comment: My point was that the semaphore lock isn't doing anything at all, no matter where you put it.  If the idea is to limit the number of tasks (client queries) running in parallel, you need a different structure to the program.  You can't use the `as_completed` function because that will start all the tasks in parallel, before the semaphore has any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `asyncio.Semaphore` and `asyncio.as_completed` the following way:

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def make_request(url: str, s: asyncio.Semaphore):
    """simulates request"""
    async with s:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

    return f"{url}: {time.monotonic()}"


async def amain():
    """main wrapper."""
    s = asyncio.Semaphore(5)
    tasks = [make_request(f"url-{i}" ,s) for i in range(26)]
    for cor in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        res = await cor
        print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```

On the other hand if you need to limit number of requests due to API timelimit, you will probably need to use some TimeLimiter from any 3rd party library.

I am author one one of such libraries [BucketRateLimiter](https://pypi.org/project/bucketratelimiter/) and I will be grateful if you use it.

Comment: This in conjunction with @Paul's comment on my question got me working code. I'll check out your repo too.